# Splat equivalent in Nancy

Tags: c#, routes, nancy

I'm trying to match all routes in a Nancy module. Sinatra uses splat parameters, e.g

```
get '/download/*.*' do
  # matches /download/path/to/file.xml
  params[:splat] # => ["path/to/file", "xml"]
end
```

Does this exist in Nancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the docs - have a look at the greedy node:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes

Comment: Cheers. I must have missed that.